What does this typography mean in the Kojiki on Wikisource?
Looking at the Kojiki on Wikisource, what does the light brown (slightly smaller) text mean toward the middle of that page, scattered about?

Also, what does the indented "blockquote" text in the gray boxes mean? What does it signify?

Finally, what do the small characters above the Chinese characters mean, are they necessary for interpreting the text, or for something else?
Thanks for the help!

I’m voting to close this question because it is about the styling and notations of a particular website, not about the Japanese language as a whole.

While "brown with smaller font" may be an arbitrary choice of this specific site, I think it's perfectly valid to ask what's happening under the hood. The answer was interesting at least to me. Another source uses uncommon brackets 【】.

The brown texts are inline notes used mainly to explain how the preceding text should be pronounced. For example, "許呂二字以音" means "for the two characters 許 and 呂, (pronounce) with phonetic readings" (that is, "KO" for 許 and "RO" for 呂). "下效此" means "hereafter, follow this (rule)".
At the time when Kojiki was written, Japanese people had not yet invented hiragana or katakana, and they of course didn't know the Latin alphabet. Therefore, they had no choice but to use Chinese characters to write even truly native Japanese words, including proper nouns from mythology. These annotations are used to indicate that the preceding letters should be treated as mere phonetic symbols (aka man'yōgana), not as ideographs (which is the original function of kanji). This system was eventually replaced by hiragana/katakana, Japan's own phonetic characters.
The gray block quotes are genuine block quotes, i.e., they are quotations of someone's poems (waka) or other such content. That "夜久毛多都～" is known as the oldest waka in history (translation here).
The small characters above the kanji are kanbun kundoku versions of the same text. Only a small subset of the text has kundoku annotations, but this is likely because the person who input this simply gave up halfway :)
You can see the photographs of the oldest known copy of Kojiki in the National Diet Library's digital archives, if you're interested. You can also see how inline notes are inserted using the warichū style.

So how do we know which part is to be pronounced as phonetic symbols (assuming the original manuscripts didn't have this feature)? That is, before someone added it, how did they know where to add it (as opposed to just treating those as non-phonetic symbols)?

@Lance These inline notes are already included the oldest known copy of kojiki (although in small warichu text rather than brown text). See the photographs.
